# Would filtering by order ID from nvarchar(MAX) column benefit from fulltext search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, full-text-search

In my table I have a `nvarchar(MAX)` column which holds data about our orders in XML form. Another department often has to get information from the table by, most commonly, looking for a certain order ID in that column but we all need to be able to look for any part of the text in the column.

The problem is that the order IDs and other filter/search criteria are unique to each order and are not words I can define in stopwords or stoplists and new ones are generated for new orders, ofc.

Since the table is growing in size queries with a `LIKE` clause take a really long time, yet I cannot think how my colleagues can get information about an order except by looking for things like its order ID, a part serial number or a piece of text. We have no control over the XML order data, furthermore it doesn't have a standardised structure, which is to say every order type has its own XML structure and there are too many to separate into different tables and we can't extract separate elements into different columns as we don't have control over the processing, only over the storage of the data.

Since an index would be futile in this case I started reading about fulltext search, but would that help because of the reasons I mentioned and if `not` is there a better alternative?

**EDIT:**

Adding example messages being stored in the nvarchar(MAX) column (there are approx. 23 other types not shown here, for the moment):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ServiceRequest>
    <OrderID>GT123456789123465</OrderID>
    <CreatedBy>some.person</CreatedBy>
    <CreationTime>2021-08-18</CreationTime>
    <CustomerReference>INC123456</CustomerReference>
    <CustomerContract>123456</CustomerContract>
    <ShortDescription>A little bit of text</ShortDescription>
    <StockLocation>Text-Identifier</StockLocation>
    <DueDate>2021-08-19</DueDate>
    <ExpectedDeliveryDate>2021-08-19T10:30:00</ExpectedDeliveryDate>
    <ServiceLevel>Same-Day</ServiceLevel>
    <DeliveryLocation>SITE</DeliveryLocation>
    <Site>Address of a building or something</Site>
    <ContactName>Name of a person</ContactName>
    <ContactPhone>0123456789</ContactPhone>
    <DocTypeID>123</DocTypeID>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <Address1>Address1</Address1>
        <Address2>More details about address</Address2>
        <City>Some city</City>
        <Postcode>LOL KEK</Postcode>
        <Country>Narnia</Country>
    </DeliveryAddress>
    <Parts>
        <Part>
            <UniqueID>168468468</UniqueID>
            <PartNumber>#ABCDE-1234-ABCDE</PartNumber>
            <Description>Example TV set with model name</Description>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Returnable>Y</Returnable>
            <ReturnInformation>TBC</ReturnInformation>
            <LinkedDemandId>123456789</LinkedDemandId>
        </Part>
    </Parts>
</ServiceRequest>
```

.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Engineer>
    <PersonId>some.guy</PersonId>
    <SearchName>Some Guy</SearchName>
    <personemail>some.guy@company.com</PersonEmail>
    <PersonPhone>00000000000</PersonPhone>
    <Address>
        <Zip>LOL KEK</Zip>
        <CountryId>US</CountryId>
    </Address>
</Engineer>
```

.

```
<WarehouseUpdate>
    <WarehouseId>Warehouse-name-123456</WarehouseId>
    <WarehouseDescription>Friendlier WH name</WarehouseDescription>
    <CurrencyId>USD</CurrencyId>
    <CostDomainId>MAIN</CostDomainId>
    <NodeId>SSL</NodeId>
    <SupplySource>W</SupplySource>
    <ReturnWarehouse>Warehouse-ID</ReturnWarehouse>
    <IsAutoReceive>Y</IsAutoReceive>
    <IsRepairWhse>N</IsRepairWhse>
    <IsReplenishable>Y</IsReplenishable>
    <SupplyWarehouse>Warehouse-ID</SupplyWarehouse>
    <WarehouseTypeId>ABC</WarehouseTypeId>
    <Address>
        <Zip>LOL KEK</Zip>
        <CountryId>US</CountryId>
    </Address>
</WarehouseUpdate>
```

.

```
<briefing>
    <incident>
        <serviceProvider>A long name of a company that provides a service</serviceProvider>
        <receiverURL>https://www.google.com/some/url/that/is/used</receiverURL>
        <incidentNumber>123456789</incidentNumber>
        <taskNumber>123456789</taskNumber>
        <taskAssignmentID>123456789</taskAssignmentID>
        <taskCreationDate>2021-02-31</taskCreationDate>
        <taskCreationTime>10:32:13</taskCreationTime>
        <sendDate>2021-02-31</sendDate>
        <sendTime>10:32:27</sendTime>
        <request>ABC</request>
        <urgency>ABC</urgency>
        <severity>D</severity>
        <customerName>Name of a company</customerName>
        <helpdeskNumber>123456789</helpdeskNumber>
        <originalCustomerReference>123456789</originalCustomerReference>
        <projectNumber/>
        <project/>
        <callerFirstName>Some</callerFirstName>
        <callerLastName>Person</callerLastName>
        <callerPhone>123456789123456789</callerPhone>
        <callerPhoneType>ABC</callerPhoneType>
        <callerEmailaddress/>
        <callerPreferredLanguage/>
        <communicationPreference/>
        <installedAtAddress1>Address short</installedAtAddress1>
        <installedAtAddress2/>
        <installedAtAddress3>More address details</installedAtAddress3>
        <installedAtAddress4>Even more address details</installedAtAddress4>
        <installedAtCity>Washington</installedAtCity>
        <installedAtState/>
        <installedAtProvince/>
        <installedAtPostalCode>LOL KEK</installedAtPostalCode>
        <installedAtCountry>US</installedAtCountry>
        <installedAtPhone/>
        <installedAtFax/>
        <installedAtEmail/>
        <productSerialNumber>ABCDF123456789</productSerialNumber>
        <productTag>ABCDF123456789</productTag>
        <productSystem>123456</productSystem>
        <productItemNumber>123456789123456789</productItemNumber>
        <productItemDescription>This is a thingy</productItemDescription>
        <productComponentNumber/>
        <productComponentDescription/>
        <productServiceGroupNumber>12</productServiceGroupNumber>
        <customerSerialNumber/>
        <defectDescription>ABCD::ABCD::ABCD EF::ABCD EF</defectDescription>
        <orderDescription>Lorem ipsum</orderDescription>
        <taskType>In summet idit</taskType>
        <customerErrorCode/>
        <problemCode>corpsem mepsem dopsem</problemCode>
        <resolutionSummary/>
        <resolutionCode/>
        <reporteddate>2021-05-12</reporteddate>
        <reportedtime>10:30:44</reportedtime>
        <customerTimezone>EET</customerTimezone>
        <coverage>-ABC-EF-</coverage>
        <contractServiceNumber>123456789123456789</contractServiceNumber>
        <plannedStartDate>2021-05-12</plannedStartDate>
        <plannedStartTime>10:32:13</plannedStartTime>
        <plannedEndDate>2021-05-14</plannedEndDate>
        <plannedEndTime>10:32:44</plannedEndTime>
        <chargeableFlag/>
        <vkOrg>12AB</vkOrg>
        <attribute1/>
        <attribute2/>
        <attribute3>AB</attribute3>
        <attribute4/>
        <attribute5/>
        <attribute6/>
        <attribute7/>
        <attribute8/>
        <attribute9/>
    </incident>
    <incidentNotes>
        <technicianNote>Went to lunch, bought a snack</technicianNote>
        <technicianNote>AB    11.11  11/11/2021
            A huge block of text incoming
            Here a monumental, monolithic, megalithic block of text resides that has numerous details written in freeform however the person doing the thing decides
            There is some structure to the text but it is completely specific to this one type of XML message.
            
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu feugiat enim. Praesent malesuada, diam ut ornare tristique, ipsum dolor rutrum enim, et sodales lectus mi at ex. Nulla in varius nisl. Nunc non enim augue. Integer condimentum tempor lacus, non maximus tortor dictum a. Donec dapibus urna nulla, ac tempus justo sodales sed. Cras lacinia tempus lacinia. Sed fermentum libero vel lectus ornare, at egestas eros dignissim. Quisque ac vehicula erat. Morbi id ultrices sem, auctor dapibus ligula. Vivamus vestibulum consectetur ligula non viverra. Proin id mi non ipsum consectetur interdum. Aenean id posuere metus.

            Aenean diam justo, ultrices sed cursus eget, posuere eget justo. Maecenas egestas mi et rutrum auctor. Fusce tincidunt ac purus ut gravida. Proin ac condimentum nibh, id venenatis nibh. Sed eu turpis non sem venenatis posuere eu sit amet leo. Vivamus velit lacus, tempor quis dolor vel, sagittis vulputate risus. Praesent dignissim sed turpis vel porta. Duis elit ante, pellentesque sit amet nisl eu, ullamcorper varius ex. Aenean tortor ligula, posuere sed tempor eget, consequat ut orci. Vestibulum eu aliquet ante. Ut eros ex, dignissim nec accumsan eu, posuere nec ligula. Cras tempor volutpat tempor. Duis vitae dui sit amet diam porttitor viverra. Aliquam ornare, turpis ut pulvinar bibendum, urna eros sodales turpis, sed malesuada felis massa in neque. Etiam venenatis volutpat diam eget placerat. Integer ultrices vulputate neque ut ullamcorper.
        </technicianNote>
    </incidentNotes>
    <ibaseNotes>
        <serialnumberNote/>
    </ibaseNotes>
</briefing>
```

Also I think I deceived you by accident, most commonly order IDs are being searched but we need to be able to search/filter by any part of the XML message, for example I need to be able to find all messages that contain "some.person" in them. I'll go back and edit that.

Comment: You need to show some example XML that covers the various structures you describe.

Comment: If you are starting with XML, I would investigate the indexing available for that data:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: I would suggest store XML in an `xml` column. Then you can use XQuery to search. If you can show examples and define what the different structures are, we can use XQuery

Comment: Please include examples of the existing queries that are being run to obtain the data. What data is needed from the query and what data is known already about the row. If you don’t have any control over the unstructured nature of the data, who does? Do they also have recommendations as to how it can fit into your processes?

Comment: @Charlieface, could you please look at the example XMLs I have added and advise if it would still be feasable?

Answer (score 1):

**Ideally you should store XML in an `xml` column.** Then you can use XQuery to search. An XML index on the column may be wise.

But you can also cast the data to XML (at a cost of lower eficiency), like this

```
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(CAST(yourData AS varchar(max)) AS xml)
) ) v(xmlData)
```

> Cast to `varchar` is necessary because the XML is defined with UTF-8.

**Then you can use XQuery, like this for example**

```
WHERE v.xmlValue.exist('/Engineer/PersonId[contains(text()[1], "some.guy")]') = 1
   or v.xmlValue.exist('/Engineer/PersonEmail[contains(text()[1], "some.guy")] ') = 1
```

Or pass through a SQL variable

```
WHERE v.xmlValue.exist('/Engineer/PersonId[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@toSearch"))]') = 1
   or v.xmlValue.exist('/Engineer/PersonEmail[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@toSearch"))] ') = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/133051)

**To find text in any node, you can use `//*`,** which means "descend any depth, matching any node name"

```
WHERE v.xmlValue.exist('//*[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@toSearch"))]') = 1
```

That can be inefficient though.

Comment: So, just hardcode 23 different element names and `OR` them and add a new clause every time we have to add a new order type, or... ? Also what happens when I need to find any part of the text and I do not know what is the element name that houses it?

Comment: Given you a solution for that as well

Comment: Thank you, would the `//*` search be less efficient than fulltext or any other alternative? Would an XML index help with the `//*`?

Comment: Full text only really works with full words. XML index probably won't help for a wildcard search